# Picasa Web Albums API : recently uploaded photos feed not working

Tags: python, google-api, gdata, picasa

I am fetching users [recently uploaded photos](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#ListRecentPhotos) from Picasa. As per documentation sample request url:

https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userID?kind=photo&max-results=10

Response is received but not as per given sample response entry tag is missing while fetching feed in response.

**Code snippet:**

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PEM_FILE_PATH, "rb").read(),
      scope=["https://picasaweb.google.com/data/"],
      prn=userEmail
    )
PHOTOS_URL = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/%s?kind=photo&max-results=10&alt=json"
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
response, albumPhotos = http.request(PHOTOS_URL %(userEmail), 'GET')
albumPhotos = json.loads(albumPhotos)
```

In the response not getting **Entry** key which contains feed of recently uploaded photos.